# How can I load my PHP file for any HTTP requests inside a directory?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, proxy

I have a proxy I've been writing with PHP for a while.

Right now, requesting a url like `www.mysite.com/proxy/?folder/page.html` on my server will return the page at `www.theirsite.com/folder/page.html`.

I basically am having my `index.php` file use everything past `/proxy/?` as the request URI for `www.theirsite.com`. Any images are copied to the folder `/proxy/images/` and the src attributes of the `<img>` tags are changed accordingly. All this is working great.

Now I would like to change my script so that I will not need the `?` anymore. However, the url `www.mysite.com/proxy/folder/page.html` would result in an HTTP request to `page.html`, which doesn't exist on my server.

This isn't what I want. I need `index.php` to be loaded instead, so it can return the page at `www.theirsite.com/folder/page.html`. To accomplish this, I imagine I would need to use Apache's mod_rewrite, which is working with my WordPress installation.

What would I need in my .htaccess file to do this correctly, while still allowing access to files that exist in the `/proxy/images/` directory? Would this affect `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` at all?

Comment: rewrite catch all
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/$  /index.php  [R]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it working how I wanted. Here's the full contents of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /proxy/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /proxy/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now for the url `www.mysite.com/proxy/folder/page.html`, `index.php` is loaded, and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns `/proxy/folder/page.html`. Files that actually exist in the `/proxy/` folder or any subfolders do not rewrite to `index.php`, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/$  /index.php  [R]
```